# Reconstruct a list of strings from its prefixes

Tags: code-golf, array, set-theory

emanresu A [posted a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271430/reconstruct-a-list-from-its-prefixes) to reconstruct an ordered list of integers from its unordered set of unordered prefixes. Many users (beginning with [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271436/56178)) noticed that summing each unordered prefix led to a very short solution. Well, let's cruelly take that possibility away by using data that isn't integers!

A few answers from the other challenge work for this version as well; that's no problem. I'm just hoping to stimulate other answers in other languages.

(The text below is a slightly modified but mostly copied version of emanresu A's original text.)

A list of strings \$[a_1,a_2,a_3, \ldots, a_n]\$ can be uniquely represented as an unordered list of its unordered prefixes \$ [[a_1],[a_1, a_2], [a_1,a_2,a_3], \ldots, [a_1,a_2,a_3, \ldots, a_n]] \$. Both the set of prefixes and the set of elements of each individual prefix can be in any order - for example,

```
["lorem","ipsum","dolor"]
```

could be represented by any of

```
[["lorem"],["lorem","ipsum"],["lorem","ipsum","dolor"]] or
[["dolor","ipsum","lorem"],["ipsum","lorem"],["lorem"]] or
[["ipsum","lorem"],["lorem"],["dolor","lorem","ipsum"]]
```

and these are all equivalent up to order and all represent `["lorem","ipsum","dolor"]`.

Your challenge is, given an unordered list of the unordered prefixes of a (non-empty) list of strings, to return the ordered list represented by them. The list may contain repeated items. You may stipulate that the input includes the empty prefix if desired. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in each language wins!

### Testcases

Note that the order of the output *does* matter: for the third test case, for example, you must output `["consectetuer","sit","elit","adipiscing"]`, not `["adipiscing","sit","elit","consectetuer"]`.

```
[["lorem"],
 ["lorem","ipsum"],
 ["lorem","ipsum","dolor"]]
-> ["lorem","ipsum","dolor"]

[["ipsum","lorem"],
 ["lorem"],
 ["dolor","lorem","ipsum"]]
-> ["lorem","ipsum","dolor"]

[["consectetuer","sit","elit"],
 ["adipiscing","sit","elit","consectetuer"],
 ["consectetuer","sit"],
 ["consectetuer"]] 
-> ["consectetuer","sit","elit","adipiscing"]

[["consectetuer","ipsum","dolor","lorem"],
 ["lorem","ipsum"],
 ["lorem"],
 ["consectetuer","lorem","ipsum"],
 ["ipsum","ipsum","dolor","lorem","consectetuer"]]
-> ["lorem","ipsum","consectetuer","dolor","ipsum"]

[["ipsum"],
 ["nunc","ipsum","justo","in"],
 ["justo","in","ipsum","molestie","nunc"],
 ["ipsum","nunc","justo"],
 ["justo","ipsum"]]
-> ["ipsum","justo","nunc","in","molestie"]

[["elit","sit"],
 ["sit","elit","elit","sit"],
 ["sit","sit","elit"],
 ["sit"]]
-> ["sit","elit","sit","elit"]

[["pede","non","phasellus","lectus"],
 ["lectus","non"],
 ["pede","non","nunc","phasellus","lectus","sit","ipsum"],
 ["non"],
 ["phasellus","lectus","non"],
 ["pede","non","ipsum","phasellus","lectus"],
 ["ipsum","pede","non","phasellus","sit","lectus"]]
-> ["non","lectus","phasellus","pede","ipsum","sit","nunc"]

[["pellentesque","ullamcorper","semper","vestibulum"],
 ["semper","pellentesque"],
 ["pellentesque","semper","vestibulum"],
 ["pellentesque"]]
-> ["pellentesque","semper","vestibulum","ullamcorper"]
```

Comment: May i assume each string contains only letters?

Comment: @tsh I'm fine with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reconstruct a list from its prefixes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271430/reconstruct-a-list-from-its-prefixes)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>73</s> 68 bytes

```python
lambda L:reduce(lambda v,l:map(l.remove,v)and v+l,sorted(L,key=len))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRLboMwEN1zCotNQHW76DJSeoLeIIkiChOFZrBdbKP29OkY28TQIDULMh6/z4x/6sdcpHi9nXeHG1bdR1Ox920Pja2hCOOB47arVIEvPXRyAD6UlWjY8IRcy95AU7zzK/zsEERZ3gx8G7ZjeZ4fsv0@r6XQUBswFvqc563StqP/RqJ0Y/pClx95xvYhjpg05@OF1CN4lH9sw@cSx2P2/PbHly99okbwyVxXqaewok7Yn1Yb6cYizCeJO6qTCNq0QOHIn5cfJD1zoeKdQ@lL01iLSC18yYCtoaymr1fU4zikV2YTzD0dzfWSGZGjn4Jm7E66WtSl0oBotdsLWlsKwv76gcf51IwYGnrAj5azrbiLPCKseMRFXC1yAqy15CuJnLA8HjaZp/ggFHU93Z@DsHZIl8mA/rIOZ5FuYi17NZ5HDZ0PBre9Hxan9qeZGT92PJNcF5lzQy//YM/LPNL9z7Kz7Bm2AlgrmHsXXrSiA1JsDuIgNuU2Y/SraH0qPLVCWcMZfCt39ZqTtIYS9JC4lweGCvmodFegujZlmUpMFGy1Kc5FqhyRWkNvloTd0pYvEJnqW0Gu8ropb78)

An anonymous function that accepts a `L`ist of lists and returns a list as result.

Copying my answer from the original question.

- -5 bytes thank to @Mukundan314

**How does it work?**

With the input sorted by length (so `[["ipsum","lorem"],["dolor","lorem","ipsum"],["lorem"]]` becomes `[["lorem"],["ipsum","lorem"],["dolor","lorem","ipsum"]]`), for each sub`l`ist, remove the first occurrence of elements already `v`isited from `l` and mark the remaining element as `v`isited.

It works for duplicates.

Comment: -5 bytes by doing `v+l` instead of `v+[l[0]]`

Comment: @Mukundan314 freaking awesome!

Comment: 67 with `*0+v+l`

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
concat.(zipWith(\\)<*>([]:)).sortOn(0<$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVS7boMwFN3zFRbqAJWFOldJp46tOnZIGFxwGqd@Fdsd@vPUxkBiMBCpIIHxPffccx/4hNQXprRpCJOi1uAZaZS/EKU3x10peIl0nv4S@U70KT0csu39U7ovHrMsVxb9xtOH7V3WaKy0Ajuwd3dCRY1ZUmzAcMFhFyZEKrNmhUkl7E5SgAsOtty9fSnGeNdzwbGCCbdNV@FSY22wgyui7RNT@xozoopIokrCP0McDDnGbpEAi5BViWG14D8qvyJ1maKXEZcD15KKk3LDyyvOs1FauG8@QV6ZLngmqB1Kgu2yZZrT3IXxHLPMMxPTNT3WyGAqVnELs9Y6TSJLXLWpCZezPCFl/2GjXM1toe1i0mW/7T3GxoCsK0iEs5c5068YcYxkVUHfmhvSGqBz5fCKe@9IGSnF3B5f38b5G0oRK0Ut/f@JmV/8uEn6MDSS9YAJmKbpBWFuIQ75gJO@YYhwe8oyJF9BKmvCNcjBMQPt8ds0fw)

Hey, I knew my [slightly different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271452) would come in handy! Only change is needing to sort by length instead of sum, 'cause uh... well you know.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 8 bytes

```
↕ᵉtiᶻ{∕z
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVQxUsMwECzoeAWj2un5i0aF4xwgkCUTSRTQM_CAVDQpgKGkgYaf0CXPoELSWY4Vnxv7dLe7d7fy-OVDw41pa1e_c7Zomdi-eXexOP_cP252X89O7r5_HvZPm_tXu2xsX9z-nvxxLqozzpRZQ2AdworJznoyVbGVCRkmxCnnQ26ikEJEVoQoshujLTQOnIcIs9KFJ6jwSvR6JTtpG6kvy2JVEhOWkJrmZzuXqxHrEIZQbQlwlqZbEKuMjU0K2utmJHDtrTPxrLE8Oh9ArVFgnYQQJnoxSi-IxFLj6IJ6uwc3i0ugi8eXmMso2MEqzWTisN1VbUEpb6MdwYMQoL8YIyxlClo_PsHO3cfmDRIUnG6QfZqbb6jPLYNTjCh5eaVAO7C3PvK8UnXbmHWHXyy0GNzFi1t6lTcYCgW9n7oQnJWYMIXAf8A_)

The input includes the empty prefix.

```
↕ᵉtiᶻ{∕z
↕           Take a permutation of the input (non-deterministically)
 ᵉt         Take its tail (removing the first item)
   i        and its initial prefix (removing the last item)
    ᶻ{      Zip with:
      ∕         Set minus
       z        Check that the result is a singleton
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 9 bytes

```
ᵐ∑oç∆ᵐᶠZH
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVO7VcQwEAzIqIKnWJdTAjXg58AnLyCQJXOSKIF3IcQkDvgVADRAF5fdVYK-xvKtE3u1OzO7O7JfPiXcqa4xzXtFVh2phzdrrlbnX_vvp8P2Wf1-HLaPLt7_DJcXr3rNdAIMu5NdVRGhNuBY9CyHlPBeWzRFSatchtT1qWPm3JFCCCOSzkUDkympgRkwFjxEc-OeINwrUJuW91wzLq_LIi2JAYtIHefRruVKyBqIEVhLBJyl8RbzNSZmBra0kk3It1Yb5c8ylifnf1CnBGjDwYWBXoyRBCOx1JhcSrJ4dLAwHi_OLy6Ug1gPbZhF-SH7m0aDEFZ7C9zeLoiexjjCQqagpbERdu48NW2UwOB4g-zP0nxjfWmZOEWmpMWFAGlA31vPsUI0HVObPn6d0MXgwV_W2oo8_Vgo6GniQnBRomTW8R__Aw)

The input does not include the empty prefix.

Using [@xnor's trick in emanresu A's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271436/56178).

```
ᵐ∑oç∆ᵐᶠZH
ᵐ∑          Take the sum of each item of the input
            Strings are automatically converted to code points and padded with zeros
  o         Sort
   ç        Prepend zero
    ∆       Take the differences
     ᵐᶠZ    Remove zeros
        H   Convert the code points to characters
```

Comment: Ha, your 9-byte found a way to bust out of Greg's guard rails :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
LÞœ^ƝṪ€
```

A monadic Link that accepts the prefixes as a list of lists of lists of characters (including an empty prefix) and yields a list of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n8Lyjk@OOzX24c9WjpjX/D7d7//8fHa2UnJ9XnJpcklpSmlqkpKOUWVBcmgukU/Jz8kF8IJmaqxSrEw1lwVQgRIAsEAfNHEzVMJOx26CDakBsLAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##dVJLTsQwDN1zCtQdUm4CF0BVkUprQUZpEiYJEls2HIA1HABxAdYjuAdcJMT5TOtOumkd@73nZyc7EOLJ@6vD@/frzc/b79fH3/OnP7xcXlx737ZtI9QepqZjJWIN18bVMqwZVchgpevY2Xkgl8JaBCHhkPBsrZzJg5IGBgvWAYIMt@ELIvyQ249cczNweUdrjPJyp4rWSXqjLx2O0Qm2dlLpeQotyvUOrOpu5mEknRwWAjtnrMKzjNXFccZMSoCxHEIY2UsjWS7xiAK5mLznvETEkf3Tcq6tbi8Ws5yGMbpRaFPf9yY8SWdwD2H4EMStpjChMEFI2XeFWxovVlYEauCqetnOhrVjeWuM5GBmzHMLAdKCeXBIdEL006D2Or1QmFLwiLd160S2f8wTdr6GleKWBqUGN90/).

#### How?

```
LÞœ^ƝṪ€ - Link: Prefixes
 Þ      - sort by:
L       -   length
    Ɲ   - for neighbouring pairs:
  œ^    -   multiset symmetric difference
     Ṫ€ - tail of each
```

Comment: You're allowed to take an empty list in the list of prefixes, so you can remove the `Ż` for [7](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n8Lyjk@OOzX24c9WjpjX/D7d7//8fHa2UnJ9XnJpcklpSmlqkpKOUWVBcmgukU/Jz8kF8IJmaqxSrEw1EUA5MEUIExEIzB1MpzGTsNuigGhAbCwA)

Comment: Thanks @emanresuA.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jcram](https://palaiologos.rocks/jcram/jcram.html), 18 bytes

```
Ⓜ⍅Ⓛ⍎⍗¹W⍜nχ0⍒⑨1βⓏ2⏛
```

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 100 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length).map(k=>a.map(a=>k.splice(k.indexOf(a),1))&&a.push(...k),a=[])&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxdDoMgEITvwoOBBDfpAewVegDDw4qrUhGIYNPbU0k0TX9edmdmZ787PjDq1YRUO99THpqMzRUh@jVxjrITxVlyY5rq7hACFgx8Lpci9ocZYrBGE5/BuJ6et4GjkBchqgohbHHiADALiU2rSpa1d9FbAutHPvC2ZSUgnShttDLJTIjbsu/eW1/8PmlhSraHOhvvpKgvyG/1xP7Hy0@AUkLkFw) Uses a similar method to movatica's python answer.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a.some(b=>(w=b[0])==b)?[w,...f(a,a.map(b=>b.splice(b.indexOf(w),1)))]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNbpwwFN7PKSw2gxXXareJPFl100Wy6BJ5YcAkjgwm2GRSVb1BpW66bO/R8@QCPcLUxphgAtVoJOb5ve/73p/hgT0xXXSiNe8aVfLTqSKMHBjWquZpTg7pkeTZewoJyeF1dkQY4ypliOGatS6eY91KUVgsFk3Jn2@r9AjRBwghvczo6SrbAZBlWSJVx@uEomChRLS6X/OgpFTWk1CKwH9io27wL/Wd5bFomfEs3UI1mheGm547CS2MfXJp/5wyK0UrdCGauziGYp6Drgi9cfuStlOiecLNGuNW0BkjX6nvLTTIrsujtU6Ww13kCArTPqJdupxN3xQz/kOvjXLnZojOjq@YWkmujeDWHNjz0kc5z4sUZjdimSzU0MzFX4sdFxP2GW1rNba4QkNwSKyXnICacrW8HPpSrpb2nmkuZa/dDuxUrTFs1Jse5RwRaWxmhRtSzoYfBNbAq@phdBulTeGtNnwFgTEMxYOmtHP0KBNUPdnvfDYxKXljuH7sHbaXktWF6lr/ZvHaG09uqXkvx8Ynf8T23UZyWwIxb@jjDGZcHqU7usOV6j6y4j5NMym0QYA/t@4FKikE5AC@AskN6LgGBFSpQ8Ar4F4ye02xVHfpp8@3N1ibzn4vRPUltUgILkBifxfAndwhAYRMuuAa7P/@@fHy66d97sEl2L/8/r6HVvYbPP0D)

Or:

```javascript
f=a=>a.some(b=>(w=b[0])==b)?[w,...f(a.map(b=>b.filter(v=>v!=w||x++,x=0)))]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNbpwwFN7PKVw2gzUuyjqRJ6tuukgWXSIvDJjEkcEUm5mpmt6gUjddtvfoeXKBHmFqY0wwgWo0EvP83vd978/wRA9U5S1v9PtaFux8LjHFe5ooWbE4w/v4iLP0ikCMM3ibHlGSJGVMk4o2NpolJReatfEB7w/v8PH5@bTboRO@ghCS65Scb9INAGmaRkK2rIoI8haKeKO6JQ@KCmk8ESEI/Cc26Hr/XN9aDovmGS/SzWWtWK6Z7piVUFybJxPmzyrTgjdc5bx@CGMo5FnogtAbtytpPSWaJlytMWwFXTDyhfreQr3ssjxa6mQ@3FkOrzDuI9ilzVl3dT7hP3VKS3uu@@jk@IqppGBKc2bMnj0tfZBzvEBhciPmyXwN9VT8tdhhMX6fwbYWY7Mr1Af7xGrO8agxV8OKvi9pa2keqWJCdMruwEzVGP1GnelQ1hGQhmYWuD7lZPheYAm8qO5Ht1LaGF5rw1XgGf1QHGhMO0UPMl7Vkd3OJxMTgtWaqc@dxXZC0CqXbePeLFY542CXmnViaHz0B2zXbSC3JhDy@j4uYIblEbIhm6SU7QeaP8ZxKrjSCLBTY1@ggkCA9@ArEEyDlimAQRlbBLwB9iUz1zQR8iH@@On@LlG6Nd8LXn6JDRKCHYjMbwfsyR4igPGoC27B9u@fHy@/fprnFlyD7cvv71toZL/B8z8)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 25 bytes

```
2(~.#~2|1#.=)@;\a:,]/:#&>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZLBToNAEIYTjzzFVGLXJi3aHoxdQmNi4smTV9sDwkDXLAuyu55MX8QLHnwIH0WfpsAiUujBA9mdf_5vZnbC-8dz8X22HNH55mpEl4RYpw6JwKNAYAqXQMtv5sDtw_3dp1bR7Pprcb5z7N3ibW473uTGXft0urmg9nhl8j8n64kVe84jhQhcOnZWFgbbFGIgPM0xIS5hmdQJ_EZhWt5MBHWGtMCh8R9AkAqJgUKlMQfJFCBnqkT8kGVMBkzErQpdb2npoz3pr0cNG0Nbq6d1Oldii2YYIohUQLb1JXKuJfCygZYE3HI99bXK12FrFloEA6LuYV5fmVuobxtUMzs9OkCTGg5Z9Wp8nbdwjkKhfNEImnM_CdI8q3aHSXW8olTsSfNmwEbtUs1cnTLH0QPG_GRFYc49) Setup borrowed from [Jonah's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271535/64121).

Sort by length, join adjacent prefixes, take the element that appears an odd number of times.

---

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 27 bytes

```
2(0{~:#])/\a:>@;/:~&.>/:#&>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZKxTsMwEIYlxjzFlYqaSjQtDIg6aoSExMTESjuE5JIaOU6IbRakvghLGHgKngSeBicOIU06MET2_fd_d-dT3t6fyq-T5Yieby5HdEmIc-ySGFYUCJzBAqj5Zi7c3N_dfmgVz64-L04Xrzs63kzn64D6196c7iauP6fjiW8d30frqZOs3AcKMXjUJB0MtxkkQHhWYEo8wnKpU_iNoszcbAR1hrTAvvEfQJgJiaFCpbEAyRQgZ8ogQcRyJkMmklaFrtdY-mhP-utRw9bQ1uppnc6V2KI5RggiE5BvA4mcawncNNCSgGfWU1-rfB22ZqFFOCDqHvb1lbmF-rZBNbvTgwM0qeGQVa_G13kL5ygUymeNoDkP0jAr8mp3mFbHC0rFHjVvBmzULtXM1SlzGN1j7E9Wlvb8AQ)

Sort each prefix, sort by length. For each pair adjacent prefixes: Take the first *different* value from the longer prefix.

Comment: Very nice  insight

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

*-2 bytes thanx to Mukundan314*

```python
lambda p,l=[]:[[*map(q.remove,l),l:=q+l][-1][0]for q in sorted(p,key=len)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVS7jtQwFK1o5iusNEnAs4IOjZSVtkECUSBtmXWRTTy7Acf2xPZI-y00IyEo-R_4Gnz9mI0zidgmub4-59xXcr__kk_6UfDTj31199Po_fb9n0-sGe67BknMqprs6vr10MjicDXSQRwpZiVmu-rwhpF6-47Ub8lejOiAeo6UGDXtCom_0aeKUV4Sr_j31e-2UVShCuV5XtcZE1YrIzhaOOulMksenHXCejJC0PYard5urGh0zcXB8jA8D_d_0VZwRVtNtaHAV722T8rsC2Sbrpe9anv-kN7hlAfQBSGC0cwfE1qPiqcxlzJMa7jsxmWrF7K7hEbZZfl5vSt9nUWJGiHK8wwhIDe8nVC_GqUFnLm7nRyfMYNgVOmeWtOxp3kHOc9LFJIvYR4uZsGn8i7TMA0VvoRkRIt3s0_HXYaoas6KOAgkaecqEpCDfLT_EWNGQettK63hBulNjwJHQgpFLHBjtEnbo8ASeFE9tmwltfP1Whk-g8gIHfGwc-ApPghFXU_38_btYnbzaKoOBmCG2WXWilH6H4kO3jjCJO8NC1Wf_Qnbl5rIrQmkvFDEC7hpgsRuxysl7eiL_I7n5WYDqxVWJ2xXt0J3G2RtiZEwWtp9ynqlC1jP9Ngw7DBRAZLIy7K0jNHt3n1hmXCUY891UWcfbj5-til8ubm9zUhtQVUFsqT0a_t08u9_)

Comment: 72 bytes: `lambda p,l=[]:[[q,*map(q.remove,l),l:=l+q][0]for q in sorted(p,key=len)]`; I don't remember if this is an acceptable output format though; fixing it would requires 3 bytes tying it with the current 75 bytes

Comment: 74 bytes: `lambda p,l=[]:[[*map(q.remove,l),l:=q+l][-1][0]for q in sorted(p,key=len)]`; this one doesn't have any caveats

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>83</s> 77 bytes

```perl
sub{map{$r{$z}--;%t=%r;++$t{$_}for@$_;($z)=grep$t{$_}==1,@$_}sort{@$a-@$b}@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LasMwELz3K4JYN3Zjxc4hl4gFfUB77Mk1RnHkIPALSSnURr9eVbil4DaXmWVmdnZHqdujhwa9uZ3nTowz6BkmRymLLEaa7XZgZ6hcM2gOFYthSvCq5fitIh7SIDszaDtzEJTD2fHKeWayDd0/ZVkY3oqFSgjEBcp30TLe4SM0MRcJM@KD8I4wqDFnXGOcsGhBmHC7Zb4oSD30RtZW2pvUJCVG2YCyDVSmm4KIixqVqVV/XZvpenHJ3qn6r5flQ7j60/EbWTXfN/9@ttjl5zBaFfo9fTnu80Me@FkZezq9WtVio7SxnvZf)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¯IévDysõ.;õK«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0HrPwyvLXCqLD2/Vsz681fvQ6v//o6OVkvPzilOTS1JLSlOLlHSUMguKS3OBdEp@Tj6IDyRTc5VidRSioUyYEiQhMBPNHCyKYUZjt0IH1YTYWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##jVIxTsQwEPxK5NriAxTX0PGEKEUuWYGRY4dbO1IKWh7ALxAF1X3g8hM@EmxvHOI7R6KJ17s7s7PjaKyPAuZhPLDi5/2jYIdxvnzj9Dk8jDid7@6n8@Pla37jc1mWTOoTdKziRQw5Ez3abIqzVrsMq3ytXJM3FCGkVn7NStBGK4TGgLHge1AY9wXpjoCtW9ELbIR6Sos8BYbeDNVtPj823Yr/y4vczExzpM6P4Fl1G7iyqtmgXywa7e@Kypv7X1OnJaAR4MIAT3QshARMObbvsri8mph4ny9ev10oE1sPbVCjvcz@uUaQ0qJ3wa3uArKVYmoLmQS2CM@g4@itbStFrj0/IDq0p2@t7y1DKiIkbi4lKAP4aj3ISll3jT719ItCR8Hg3@toZZS/FhL4Ijkh3KVIkVX1Cw).

**Explanation:**

```python
¯              # Push an empty list; result-list starts with []
 I             # Push the input-list of lists
  é            # Sort it by length (shortest to longest)
   v           # Pop and loop over each inner list `y`:
    D          #  Duplicate the current result-list
     y         #  Push the current loop-list `y`
      s        #  Swap so the duplicated result-list is at the top
       õ.;     #  Replace every first occurrence in `y` with an empty string
          õK   #  Then remove those empty strings
            «  #  And merge the remaining single item to the result-list
               # (after the loop, the result-list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 40 bytes

```
({.,1$:^:(0<#)@}.](1}.i.|.[)&.>{.)@/:#&>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZLBTsJAEIYTjzzFIMq2Caz0YmQRQmLiyZNXxATLUNZst5Xd9YI8iRc8-FDwNG67tZbCwUOzOzP_N__spJ9fr9vdZb_Jgul1k_UJaZxTsoAhAwId6AGzX5fC3ePD_bfRi-7NzvPWtBNcsGfm9W5b_nhDp16woZx-0InfpqM19cdXrNUeOf3-7MlvREM6YbCAAbOCBobLBCIgIllhTAaEp8rE8BvNE3tzEeQVUgKHwn8AYSIVhhq1wRUorgEF1xaZzXnKVchlVGahqrWSOlpL_XnksBOUvWq5inOWLNEU5wgykZAuZwqFMAqENTCKwMCuJ79m9TwsxdLI8IjIPdzrM3EJ1WVH3dxOTw5QlI6HzLwKXeUtQqDUqN4MghFiFofJKs12h3F2vKPS_MWIYsAiW6WKuSptTqMHjPvJtlt3_gA)

This approach is more or less a port of [Arnauld's recursive approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271513/15469).

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 45 bytes

```
[:,@(2~.&>@-.~&>/\a:,]/:#&>)(a:-.~&,<\/.~)&.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZAxT8MwEIX3/ooTSHEjpQ7q6NAoAokJMbC2DCG9tkaOE@qYBdG/HmwnmDStKhii@N69797Zb@0VJRtYMCAQwQ0w880o3D8/PrRLFmXT@YEGaTajhyCNVzmLXmJ2HaThNGdWi25XMT2EAU3bcPJ0R8HJl0DT8Ywj/pXiiGmSfRo9ig3yxcJV5syuNR@PmGwXdMlgAwmzOBa7CrZARLXHkiSE10qX8FOtK3PqKnAd4oFj4x@AopIKiwYbjXtQvAEUvDFIvuY1VwWXW6/C0GssY3Qk/WY4uDP4WSNtkGxFj9a4RpCVhHqXKxRCKxAmQCsCiXked7R9V3qz1LI4IVxGd3tr9tDYdjKte9OzC/St0yVtVu8b3EUIlA2qd42ghcjLotrX9u2wtL8PVA1/1aJfsFeHVL/XYMx59IhpvwE)

Kinda long, but possibly interesting approach to dealing with repeats:

- `(a:-.~&,<\/.~)&.>` A pre-processing step that goes through each set and replaces repeated items by actually repeating them.  This allows our main code to assume uniqueness.

  - Eg, conceptually, if we have a list like `[a, b, a]`, it becomes `[a, b, [a, a]]`.  We use nested J boxes for this.
- The remaining steps may now assume no repeats.
- `a:,]/:#&>` Sort the sets by their length, and add an empty set to start
- `2...-.~&>/\` Do consecutive set differences to recover the original list
- `~.&>@` Uniquify each to undo the effect of the first pre-processing step
- `,@` Flatten the result

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 69 bytes

```python
lambda p:[s for s,in sorted(p,key=len)if[r.remove(s)for r in p if r]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVTNbpwwED71sk9hcQEkJ-cqEpVyaKRKPVTKkXAgYBq3xnaxvVKepZeVqvbY92mfpjPY3mAW1FxgPP6-b_5gvv_Sz_ZJydOPoXr46exw9fbPe9GOj31L9E1tyKAmYiiXxKjJsr7Q9Ct7rgSTJR_q6XpiozqywpSImwjgNOEDmZrGi_1987trDTOkInme13UmFFCyhkaLZlwbt-WhWa_AkzUNuXpHdm8PIBpda3G0PIyuw_1ftFPSsM4y6xjyDbfwZAJeKNv2XHPTcfk5vaMpD6EbQg0lK39MaD8qXcbcyjCt4bIbl63eyO4SGmW35df17vR1FSVqhCgvM8SA0sluQf3ijFV4lvPt4viCGZVgxnIG5sxe5h3kPC9RSL6EdbiYhVzKz5mGaZjwJSQj2rxbfTrzZYhq1qyIw0Ca9XNFCnPQT_AfCeEMth5aCcY8SG96FDoSUihigxujLdoeBbbAm-qxZTupna_3yvAZREboiIedAy_xQSjqerqft2-XgL1kmfnmEOYE7LFOTdr_SGz0xhEn-ehEqPrsT9i-1ERuTyDlhSJewU0TbGA7XhsNoy_yB5mXhwMuVFyduFPnFXpzIGBrSpSzGvap4MYWY6sLdmwFnTFRAZPIy7IExjTv3qEAJh71xKUt6uzu9sNHSOHT7f191tQAqiqUbUq_tk8n__4H)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 73 bytes

```python
lambda p:p and(m:=min(p,key=len))+f([q for q in p if q!=m!=q.remove(*m)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVTNbpwwED71sk_hcAFSJ-dqJSLlEilSD5VyJBwImMSpsQ22V8qz9LJS1R77Pu3TdIztDWZB7QXG4-_75g_m20_5pl8EP37viscfRndXn37fs7p_amsk9xLVvM36fdFTnkn8lbwVjPA8_9hl5YA6MaIBUY4koh0aLor-ohiuR9KLA8ku-7zKneCfD7-aWhGFCpSmaVkmTAAoqXCwcEKlMmsenLQCPElVoasbtHm7A9HgWopby8HwMty_RRvBFWk00YZYvqIanoTBy8rWLZVUNZQ_x3c45lnoilCF0cIfEtqOiucx1zKMazjvxnmrV7I7hwbZdfllvRt9XUQJGj7K-wxtQG54M6O-GqWFPfPpdnZ8x_SCEaUpAXNiz_P2co4XKURfwjJcyILP5adM_TSU_xKiEa3eLT6d6dJHVUtWwNlAkrRTRcLmIF_gP2LMKNt6aCUY0yCd6VDWEZF8ESvcEG3W9iCwBl5VDy3bSO10vVWGyyAwfEcc7BR4jvdCQdfR3bxduxhsKE3UYCzMMNhljRil-5FI74yDneSTYb7qkz9iu1IjuS2BmOeL-A9unGAF2_FaSRh9lj7yNN_t7Ia1q9Mu2WmF7ncIbImRMFrCPmVU6ayvZUYONcMTJijYJNI8z4ExTru3y4Bpj3KkXGdlcnd7_xlS-HL78JBUJYCKwsqGtX08uvdf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｗ⌊Φθ⁼Ｌκ⊕Ｌυ⊞υ⊟Φι›№ικ№υκυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLCsIwFET3fkXoKoX4BV2KiqDQfcgipBcbzKPNQz8/9qpBfMzi3plhOGqUQXlpSrmN2gChJ@20zZbutEkQ6MzIds7SRHoEd04jvbSMHJwKYMElGGqd24dIn@MSGOn9VBGakX0AiXbjs0tYIOUZMgZUt@qDxqLtSuGcN8q7CCpByhAa1ugpZrv8wRuPeblgG8H4y9XFu0H3BfmdVux/PPsECCHK@mru) Link is to verbose version of code. Accepts but does not require the empty prefix. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⌊Φθ⁼Ｌκ⊕Ｌυ
```

While there is a prefix with one more member than the number of terms collected so far, ...

```
⊞υ⊟Φι›№ικ№υκ
```

... find any terms that appear more times in that prefix than in the terms collected so far and push one to the (predefined empty) list of terms so far.

```
υ
```

Output the final list.

Differences between this solution and the numeric solution:

- Slightly different way of retrieving the next prefix, since I need to refer to it twice
- Different method of finding the next term, of course
- Resulting list is of strings so only takes 1 byte to output

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 101 bytes

```python
lambda l,p=0:[PyObj_FromPtr(-p+(p:=x))for x in sorted(sum(map(id,b))for b in l)]
from _ctypes import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVTNatwwED714qcQvthutKXHsuBCLoFCoQs5Oib4R24UZEm15JB9ll4WSnvs-7RP05FkbSyvTXPZHc983zd_9nz_JY_6QfDTjy6_-znqbvfhD2FVX7cVYljm7_fF4filfry_GUR_0EO6k1ep3OfPWdaJAT0jypESgyZtqsY-7SuZ0hbXLlqbKMvKqAMyum_0URKFaC-B8NYl-_vmd1Mp8OYoSZKiiJkYSB-X2Fs4phKUVzw4bgV44rJEu49oMxqBqHctxY3lYHiZ7v-ijeCKNJrokRi-ohp-CYM_I1u1VFLVUP41jOGQZ6ArQiVGC78vaDsrnudcqzDs4XIal6Neqe4S6mXX5Zf9bsx1kcVrTFledmgS8pE3M-rjqLQwz9xGZ48vmF4wojQlYFr2vO5JzvECheBNWKbzVfC5vK102oaa3oRgRauxxatjg1NWtWR5nEkkSWs7EqYG-QDfEWOjMqOHUYJhF-lMhzKOgDQ1scL12WZj9wJr4FV1P7KN0s7hrTZcBZ4xTcTBzonn-EnI6zq627cbF2OEa6K-jQY2MrhzjRik-5BI74wns8l6ZFPXZ3_Adq0GclsCIW9q4hXcsMASruM7JWH1aXLHkyyKzIE1p9PcWHtC9xECW2IkRi3hnjKqtD3I5Kli2GK8gikiybIMGIO9vV0KTPMoB8p1WsQ3158-QwmH69vbuCwAlOdGtszc2T6d3P8_)

-6 bytes thanks to Mukundan314.

Direct adaptation of [xnor's answer for integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271430/reconstruct-a-list-from-its-prefixes/271436#271436), converting the strings to and from integers using [`id` and its inverse `_ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids/15012814#15012814).

Comment: -6 bytes by replacing `id(a)for a in b` with `map(id,b)`

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 58 bytes

Prompts for a nested vector of nested vectors of strings.

```
 i←↑r←m[⍋∊⍴¨m←⎕]⋄⍎∊(⍴r)⍴⊂'r←1↓1↓¨(¯1+r⍳¨r[1])⌽¨r⋄i←i,↑r⋄'⋄i
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##fVJNToNAFN5zCnbQaBfEU5hoPEDTBcK0jhkYZBgTt6apTSuNxvQO3bnQrRuOMhfBNzNAGTotCcyb773ve3@EGRnHLyGh83FEQsZwVIvt7vZGLD@uHLCu78AKHLF6m9UYTLH8zOFIJqLciNValL/VPpH4djcVm4Uot4D6AOcj@Ij1qyfDA7H8km@196vv4CIX5U@1zyfBdCTe/8ACphTHl0p@s/AkUENSp545/qWUITRHiTdy/cZyPZwxbkNcL6aAgMcBcgd2AgM5HewOZRU3oilDUYEKjmQIwwV8EYFDMsMYZ5hFOJ2bPtfkyVCLUFuJGWtLa7blnhvFoLeB0PHkWml7iqNGnHYbB4WUp1FP4JGzgsp7qry96yEmoQSxAiMwFbtfSCOneYZCby3NlJspmqO3@szFqQ5UgFLLUKxKobLG7CFkiBDO5BCgczDUoLWpoyRgkJqiLdw2tbmgTsRGsGZox3OivM59qhVdRcto2iYEpQViT1xyOCFhEtE80z8oSrTxLDd1z0mz7Q432LpcQ@6EgGp/wD3z/AM)